# Using blob storage as an image repository

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm building an ecommerce app where each product has product images associated with it. I want to store these product images in a blob storage, but I don't think I'm fully clear on how my ecommerce app would access the correct images for each product in an efficient manner.

I know that blob storage accounts don't have true directories, but I also know that we can simulate "virtual" directories by including them as part of the blob/file name.

With that said, is my only option to group images together by putting them in the same virtual directory that's named after a unique identifier such as the `product ID`?

**For example:** if a user is looking at `product ID 730`, then the ecommerce app should look for images in the blob directory `/products/730/`.

Am I on the right track? Is this my only option here or is there a better way to do this? Perhaps I can include `product ID` as indexed blob metadata as well.

Comment: Yes, that is how blob storage should be used to categorize data. The more abstract you can be with your paths, the better.

Comment: @Andy Is there any added benefit to including product ID as part of the blob metadata and searching by that instead?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt -- If you think it's something that you could use, then go for it. You don't get charged extra to store metadata, so go for it. Just remember that if anything changes, you have to change it in 2 places instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your consideration is correct that put the image in such a virtual directory `/products/730/`. And currently, it should be best way to do that.

Regarding "include product ID as `indexed blob metadata`", if you mean [Blob Index tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal), this feature is currently in preview and only supports a few regions. So it's not a good idea as of now.